# Range of re-parameterized function

Tags: real-analysis

I am little confused here.

Let us define a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where

$\begin{equation*}
\mathop{f}(t)= \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
 2\sqrt t & \mbox{if}\; 0\leq t < \frac{1}{2},\\
 5\sqrt t & \mbox{if}\; \frac{1}{2}\leq t \leq 1.
 \end{array} \right.
 \end{equation*}
$

Then the re-parameterized function with $t\mapsto t^2$, will be

$\begin{equation*}
\mathop{f}(t^2)= \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
 2t & \mbox{if}\; 0\leq t < \sqrt \frac{1}{2},\\
 5t & \mbox{if}\;\sqrt \frac{1}{2}\leq t \leq 1.
 \end{array} \right.
 \end{equation*}
$

Could anyone please tell me is it right or not. I have doubt about the range of the re-parameterized function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks good to me.

$f(t)$ maps $[0,1/2)$ to $[0,\sqrt{2})$ and $[1/2,1]$ to $[5/\sqrt{2},5]$.

$f(t^2)$ maps $[0,\sqrt{1/2})$ to $[0,\sqrt{2})$ and $[\sqrt{1/2},1]$ to $[5/\sqrt{2},5].$

So, the range is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also, range are same but the partition of the domain changes. Though it is consistent with the transformation.